# Have you visited here within a month / within the last month? Which is correct?

Tags: word-usage

I'm learning English from a TV show and a textbook.
I showed some dialogues to a native speaker and she pointed out a sentence.
This is the context.

> Officer : **Have you visited Vietnam within a month?**
>
> Dave : No, I haven't.
>
> Officer : Okay. How long are you staying in Vietnam?
>
> Dave : For 12 days. I don't need a visa, right?
>
> Officer : That's correct. You can stay in Vietnam for 15 days without
>   a visa. Do you have a return ticket?
>
> Dave : Yes, here it is.

She said - It should say "within the last month". We would understand it but it would be better to say "have you visited Vietnam within the last month" or "the past month"

**I think if she is correct, it's because 'within a month' means 'before a particular period of time has passed from now' so it's not allowed to say with present perfect. Am I correct or are there any other reasons?**

A native speaker is a co-host of the show and I heard there are some proofreaders before the book publishes. That's why I am confused and double-checking.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that she is correct, but your reason is not quite correct. The meaning of "within a month" is clear from the context but the phrase sounds incomplete; within a month of what? That could refer to a period of a month from a date in the past just as much as to a period starting now. On its own the phrase is either the beginning or end of something. So you could have "within a month of New Year's Day" or, but not in this context "You will have to leave here within a month".

Comment: Thank you so much, JeremyC.

You answer sounds like we need a starting point to say 'within'. So when we say 'within a month' for future, current is a starting point. Also when we say 'within the last month' with present perfect, current is a base time too.

Comment: Yes. "He graduated from college in May 2017. Within a month, he had landed a job with a prestigious investmen bank" (before one month has elapsed).

Comment: "Their birth dates are all within a month of yours"—here it goes in both directions. But yes, there always needs to be a starting point. In the show, I assume, the officer is Vietnamese, so even American or English screenwriters will try to reproduce some kind of a broken English.

Comment: Oh, placing a starting point in a different sentence in your example is very interesting. I also think the writer of the book traveled Vietnam a lot so she could hear the sentence many times.

Comment: There is a reason "within the next/last thirty days" is used instead of "month."

Answer (score 0):

> Have you visited Vietnam within a month?

*within a month* implies a future month, but then you used a past participle in the question and in the answer:

> No, I haven't.

## To fix this mess

If your intention is to ask about a time span in the past, you'll want to change your question to

> Have you visited Vietname within the last/past month?

If you intention is to ask about a time span in the future, you'll want to change your question to

> Will you visit Vietnam within a month? (meaning "*within the next*")

Comment: @user3547458 Great! Feel free to accept this answer by clicking the check mark.

Comment: @JonathanKomar It should be "Present Perfect", not "past participle" (I don't have enough reputation to edit it directly).